# How to add legend to a histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a histogram of fee_rate broken down by sex stored in a data frame called fees.

To plot the same I used the following code:

```
axarr = fees.hist(column='fee_rate', by = 'gender')


for ax in axarr.flatten():
 ax.set_xlabel("fee_rate")
 ax.legend(gender)
```

I need to have a legend on the plot which says the plot is by for male or female. However using the above code, I get "Female" on both the plots. Can someone point out the error?

Comment: Can you show some or all of your dataframe? Ideally convert is to a dictionary using df.to_dict() method, print the dictionary and copy and paste it as code, so we can use it to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It appears as if the titles already indicate that the left graph is for females and the right for males. So one option would be to leave out the legend altogether.
- If you insist on having a legend on top of that, you can try `ax.legend((ax.get_title(),))`.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate legend for these two plots is not the sex, but the word 'tip_rate', since that's what's being plotted.  The sex is already being displayed as the title of each subplot. You can verify this by setting the legend = True. If you choose to do this, you can get rid of your loop which labels the x_axis.  Alternatively, you can forget about the legend altogether and use you loop to label the x_axis.

```
tips.hist(column='tip_rate', by = 'sex',legend=True)
plt.suptitle('TIP RATES BY SEX')
plt.show()
```

[image]